# Using Javascript is it possible to hook a custom function to the browser back button while preventing the default event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript is it possible to hook a custom function to the browser back button while preventing the default event?

So simply put, the user clicks the browser back button,  and instead of being taken back to the previous page on my site, my function fires. My aim is not to to prevent the user leaving my site.

Something like the below pseudo code:

```
window.backbutton.click(function(e){ preventDefault(e); myFunc(); })
```

FYI What I actually have is an internal back/forward system controlled by buttons within the view and I'd like to trigger my buttons when user clicks browser back.

Comment: You want to hijack my back button?

Comment: it's a pretty bad design idea

Comment: You can do some tricks, such as using hashes, so that going back will only change the hash but not leave the page. But AFAIK you can't stop it if the previous page is from another site.

Comment: updated question, I do not want to prevent them leaving my site

Comment: @Aaron Regardless of what your intentions are, if something like this were possible then it would be HORRIBLY abused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into Browser History https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history . It is a new standard for emulating pages (back and forward) on a single-page site.

Comment: This is the correct solution; have the next/forward/etc enter actual history records, and then the back button will navigate them the same as the buttons do.

Comment: That page doesn't explain much in terms of manipulating/changing the browser history, and neither does your answer.  And while that page is likely not going anywhere, it could, so it would be better to include the relevant code samples in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this
>
> ```
> $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
>     return "Are you Sure you want to do this even though there are internal navigation buttons? if you do whatever you have done so far
> ```
>
> will be gone unless it has been completed and/or submitted "; //
>   Return whatever message you want
>       });​
>
> Edit: this method displays a confirmation with the message and
>   automatically places buttons in the confirmation window
>
> the author also clearly stated he does not want to prevent users from
>   leaving his site
>
> see js fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/JW9fX/
>
> Aaron - "updated question, I do not want to prevent them leaving my
>   site –  Aaron 27 mins ago"
>
> Edit: there is no definitive way to display a message only on the back
>   button in my knowledge i have also looked and have seen the only
>   methods that pick up on the back button  are
>   `$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){return;})` and
>   `$(window).onbeforeunload = function(){return;}` and they both pick up
>   on when the page is refreshed or any other navigation away from the
>   current page. This is currently the best answer that can be provided
>   in the year 2014

Edit:

above is for all unload events

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhw2x/85/

been messing with that through all its lower objects it cant be done through javascript till someone decides to make all major browsers use a specific name for each unload event instead of it just being an unload event

so the answer is no you cannot hook a custom function to the browser back button while preventing the default event using javascript

Comment: Thanks your answer was useful +1. I think the down votes were unfair.